# Specific overtime calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a simple timesheet that should calculate overtime1 and overtime2, I just cant figure out a good way to fix it.

Normal workday on 8hrs from 07:00 to 17:00 give no overtime (eg 07:00 to 16:00 or 08:00 to 17:00), but when time exceeds 8 hours I would like to get the exceeding hours in a cell.

My business rules are:

1) Any work greater than 8 hours between the hours of 06:00 to 20:00 get paid as overtime1.

2) Any work less than 8 hours will not generate any overtime2 even if after 20:00

3) Any work performed earlier than 06:00 or later than 20:00 get paid at the overtime2 rate.

Example 1: Working from 07:00 to 18:00 would get a value of 3 hours of overtime1

Example 2: Working from 14:00 to 22:00 would generate 0 hours of overtime2.

Example 3: Working 05:00 to 21:00 would give overtime1 6 hours and overtime2 2 hours (1 hour before 06:00, 1 hour after 20:00).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculating overtime hours in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667987/calculating-overtime-hours-in-excel)

Comment: This is related, but not a duplicate. OP has additional considerations that were not present in your possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty easy problem to solve if your data is laid out smartly. With column A as clock in time and column B as clock out time, use this formula as a helper to determine if you should use the clock in time or your base of 06:00:

`=IF(A1-FLOOR(A1,2)<6/24,6/24,A1-FLOOR(A1,2))`

Then use this formula to determine if you should use clock out time or 20:00:

`=IF(B1-FLOOR(B1,2)>20/24,20/24,B1-FLOOR(B1,2))`

Then you subtract the two to get fractions of a day, multiply by 24 to convert to hours, then subtract 8 to get hours of overtime1. Combined in a super formula it looks like this in C1:

**OT1:** `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"",(IF(B1-FLOOR(B1,2)>20/24,20/24,B1-FLOOR(B1,2))-IF(A1-FLOOR(A1,2)<6/24,6/24,A1-FLOOR(A1,2)))*24-8)`

Remember, Excel formats dates where 1 = 24 hours. Also, I added in an `OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1))` statement to make sure you get a null string if one of the values is blank.

Starting on the overtime2, you need to split it into two parts: before 06:00 and after 20:00. The first part checks if the clock in time is earlier than 06:00 and if so figures out how many hours. The formula ultimately ends up being:

`=IF(IF(A1-FLOOR(A1,2)<6/24,6/24,A1-FLOOR(A1,2))<=6/24,(6/24-(A1-FLOOR(A1,2)))*24,0)`

For after 20:00, the same pattern is used. Figure out how many parts of a day were logged after 20:00. The final formula ends up being:

`=IF(IF(B1-FLOOR(B1,2)>20/24,20/24,B1-FLOOR(B1,2))>=20/24,((B1-FLOOR(B1,2))-20/24)*24,0)`

Finally, to figure out the total number of overtime 2, just add the two formulas together in D1:

**OT2:** `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"",IF(IF(A1-FLOOR(A1,2)<6/24,6/24,A1-FLOOR(A1,2))<=6/24,(6/24-(A1-FLOOR(A1,2)))*24,0)+IF(IF(B1-FLOOR(B1,2)>20/24,20/24,B1-FLOOR(B1,2))>=20/24,((B1-FLOOR(B1,2))-20/24)*24,0))`

Comment: This works fine,
But how do i add for the hours before 6 o´clock?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I would recommend building on the principle in another cell and then adding the earlier than 0600 formula to the ones above to get your total result. The result in cell E1 would be: `IF(A1-FLOOR(A1,2)>=6/24,0,6-(A1-FLOOR(A1,2))*24)`. This gives you the total number of hours that were entered that are earlier than 0600.

Comment: Almost there :)
When the field is blank, ie nothing written i get the value 6. Is there a good way around?

Comment: Sure. Wrap the entire thing in another IF statement where the condition is ISBLANK(A1). Like this: `IF(ISBLANK(A4),"",IF(A4-FLOOR(A4,2)>=6/24,0,6-(A4-FLOOR(A4,2))*24))`

Comment: When i use the `IF((IF(G4-FLOOR(G4;2)>20/24;20/24;G4)-(F4-FLOOR(F4;2)))*24-8<0;0;(IF(G4-FLOOR(G4;2)>20/24;20/24;G4)-(F4-FLOOR(F4;2)))*24-8)`
And have 01:00 to 17:00 i will get overtime 1 5hrs and overtime 2 4 hrs,
overtime 1 should show 3 hrs.
Tried to use the previous formula after in reverse but wont get it to work.

Comment: I'm not really tracking. I entered the formulas I provided in C1 and D1 again with those times and I got 8 and 0. That is a 16 hour workday (poor sucker!) which is 8 hours more than an 8 hour day (overtime1), none of which was later than 20:00 (overtime2). How do you figure 3 hours of overtime?

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe i did not explain the rules completely :).

OT1 only after 8hrs between 06:00 and 20:00.
OT2 before 6 and After 20.

So what we are missing is a rule that says between 00:00 and 6:00 no OT1.

Poor sucker working is me with no brains :P

Comment: I have modified my answer based off of your clarification. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Found a flaw when the working day starts late it generates OT2, added in the rules.
The rest works awesome!

Comment: You can solve that issue by applying an IF statement around the whole thing: IF(timeout-timein<=8 then 0, else rules for ot1/ot2). I'm glad I was able to help. If it adequately answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just about getting the logic right and understanding that Excel treats `07:00` as a decimal equal to `7/24`, for example.

**OT1**

```
=IF(NOT(AND(Sheet1!$A2>=7/24,Sheet1!$B2<=17/24)),MIN(20/24,Sheet1!$B2)-Sheet1!$A2-9/24,0)
```

**OT2**

```
=IF(MIN(20/24,Sheet1!$B2)-Sheet1!$A2-9/24,MAX(B2-20/24,0),0)
```

---

[image]